# Merge php 2d array using key

Tags: php

Best way to convert marge array for inner array. Mainly asking if there are any (php) function, as by looping I can esealy achive this.

Example

PHP array:

```
array(
array('type'=>'ORANGE', 'attribute'=>'sweet'),
array('type'=>'ORANGE', 'attribute'=>'tropical'),
array('type'=>'BANANA', 'attribute'=>'yellow')
);
```

desired output:

```
array(
array('type'=>'ORANGE', 'attribute'=>array('sweet','tropical')),
array('type'=>'BANANA', 'attribute'=>array('yellow'))
);
```

Comment: any try that you did? show us?

Comment: No, there is no build in functions for this. So you can do it with loops. PHP provides you `tools()` functions, but not `build_me_a_house()` function

Comment: As im saing im looking fo build in function like array_unique() but for marging and not eracing existing elements, as by looping i can acheve this rather simple.

Comment: thanks @Rizier123, was just searching for better solution to not reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the first array and build a new one. Code is not perfomat, but optimal to understand the buisness logic behind

```
 <?php

    $arr = array(
                array('type'=>'ORANGE', 'attribute'=>'sweet'),
                array('type'=>'ORANGE', 'attribute'=>'tropical'),
                array('type'=>'BANANA', 'attribute'=>'yellow')
            );
    $new = array();
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        $out[$a['type']]['attribute'][] =  $a['attribute']; 
    }
    $new = array();
    foreach($out as $key=>$val) {
        $new[]= array('type'=>$key,$val);
    }
    unset($out);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($new);die;

 ?>
```